# Is it possible to configure AWS sqs with jndi configuration in Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, jms, jndi, amazon-sqs

Since there is Amazon SQS Java Messaging Library, I want to know if it is possible to set up JNDI for AWS SQS. Presently the application uses com.amazon.sqs.javamessaging.SQSConnectionFactory in spring to create connectionFactory object.

Please suggest. I have googled a lot but did not find much help on AWS SQS JNDI configuration.

Comment: Were you able to connect it? Can you please share your solution if possible?